# IB displays tvOS tableviewcells with weird frames

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, tvos, xcode9.2

I am having weird bugs in IB for tvOS tableviewcells.

1. Since this is my first tvOS project, I don't know if it is intended or not but tableviewcell's content view's width is notably smaller than actual cell.

[image]

2. When I try to add any subview(UILabel, UIButton or UIView) its actual frame and content are different.

[image]

3. Lastly, when I try to resize any subview inside UITableViewCell, its frame changes immediately.

[Screenrecord1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct4SE.jpg)

I use the latest version of Xcode, Version 9.2 (9C40b). Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: Have noticed this also. A work around is to create your `UITableViewCell` layout in an `xib` and register it when your `UITableView` initializes.